# Loading image/bar before sending mails in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, progress-bar

I want to show loading image or bar while server is taking time to send the email to the specified user in laravel. Is there any laravel package to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues) for that. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#queueing-mail):

> Since sending email messages can drastically lengthen the response time of your application, many developers choose to queue email messages for background sending. Laravel makes this easy using its built-in unified queue API. To queue a mail message, use the `queue` method on the `Mail` facade after specifying the message's recipients:

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($moreUsers)
    ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
    ->queue(new OrderShipped($order));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#queueing-mail

Comment: thanks for your answer... but I have to generate invoice and send mail which takes about 42 seconds to complete... What can I do for that?

Comment: @msbomrel you should still use queues. When a user clicks a link, queue the invoice generation and sending the email. When this job is completed, you can [send a notification to a user](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting) (to a web browser using broadcasting, or by sms, email etc).

Comment: okay, I have very basic knowledge about broadcasting. I will try to implement it but I am afraid that I cannot or  queuing will be slow in shared hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

```
// check for failures

if (Mail::failures()) {
    // return response showing failed emails
}else{
    return response()->json(['status'=>201],201);
}
```

//in you ajax function probably!

```
 $('#sendEmailBtn').click(function(e){

      showLoadingImage();    

      $.ajax({
          url:url,
          data:data,
          success:function(response){
               if(response == 201){
                      stopLoadingImage();
              }

          }
     });
});
```

Comment: but i have another return statement after mails which will not be implemented if i use your logic... right?